kafka aapache spark Integration
Getting this error constantly
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka' error 

using command
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.1 live_processing.py 

Can someone provide solution or suggest any alternative
